# SQL search query to Access DB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to query an Access database using a search button from a textbox and insert the results into a listbox. Here's the code I have so far:

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(DBcon)
    Try
        lbresults.Items.Clear()
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Select I.InstName, S.StuName FROM Instructor I, Student S WHERE I.InstName Like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' and S.StuName like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%'", con)

        con.Open()

        command.Connection = con
        dr = command.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            lbresults.Items.Add(dr("InstName"))
            lbresults.Items.Add(dr("StuName"))
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
```

The problem I'm having is it's returning the both InstName and the StuName multiple times in the listbox. I'm guessing it's because I'm doing the items.add twice? I was trying to use "[oledbcommand variable name].parameters.addwithvalue" but I couldn't figure out how to do it with a "like" function.

Answer (score 1):

If it's adding the InstName and StuName multiple times to the dropdownlist is probably because the query is returning the records multiple times since you are doing a `select ... where ... like...`

Try changing your select statement to (notice the word DISTINCT):

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Select DISTINCT I.InstName, S.StuName FROM Instructor I, Student S WHERE I.InstName Like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' and S.StuName like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%'", con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is  relating two tables without specifying the relationship.

There are multiple ways to skin a cat but I would do this to guarantee that I'm controlling the outcome:

```
dim SQL as new string = _
    "Select 'Instructor' as NameType, I.InstName as NameValue " _
    "from Instructor I " _
    "where I.InstName Like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' " & _
    "union " & _
    "Select 'Student' as NameType, S.StuName as NameValue " _
    "from Student  S " _
    "where S.StuName Like '%" & txtsearch.Text & "%' " 

Dim command As New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
```

Using union versus union all returns distinct records across the dataset with instructor being the prevailing table in case of duplicate names.